# COM Wrappers: Are they Managed or Unmanaged resources?

Tags: c#

I have a text editor control srtitten with VB 6.0 or VC 6.0 and now we have a AxInterop for it in the refrences and I have put it in a .NET custom control and been using it like that. So now I am wondering if this is considered a Maanged resource or an unmanaged resource?  The reason for asking this is that I am running a memory profiler tool and looking at its graphs I see like 60MB of memory allocated to Unmanaged Resources ..so was wondering if this is the culprit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COM wrappers are "Runtime Callable Wrappers" and are managed resources.  The 60MB of memory allocated to "unmanaged resources" are not the wrappers themselves, however may well be as a result of the underlying COM object whose lifetime is generally tied to that of the RCW.

See [Runtime Callable Wrapper on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe.aspx)

Comment: Great. RCW. And I sometimes get RCW error when closing the form that has this COM wrapper in it. So you mentioned "however may well be as a result of the underlying COM object whose lifetime is generally tied to that of the RCW." So how can I determine or debug that? or how to correctly release the underlying one too?

Answer (score 1):

**Long story short**: any wrappers are managed resources and COM wrappers as well. No long story itself.

There is a simple separation between managed and unmanaged resources in .NET.
Unmanaged resources is something that CLR is not aware of like `IntPtr`, raw handles and other low level "handles" obtained from the unmanaged world.

```
// handle is a native resource
IntPtr handle = ObtainResourceFromNativeWorld();

// ... using handle

// Releasing resource
ReleaseResourceToNativeWorld(handler);
```

But when you'll wrap this `IntPtr` into the class that implements `IDisposable` interface with `Finalizer` method, this class itself would be a Managed resource.

```
// NativeWrapper is a managed resource
class NativeWrapper : IDispoable
{
  // _handle is a native resource
  private readonly IntPtr _handle;

  public NativeWrapper()
  {
    _handle = ObtainResourceFromNativeWorld();
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    Dispose(true);
  }

  ~NativeWraper()
  {
    Dispose(false);
  }

  private void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    // because we're dealing with native resources
    // we should release them from both: Dispose method and Finalizer
    ReleaseResourceToNativeWorld(_handle);
  }
}
```

Conclusion: raw handle is a native resource but class that wraps native resource in a class is a managed resource. (Strictly speaking managed resource is a class that wraps native or managed resource. I.e. any class that will contain our wrapper would be managed resource as well).

Comment: Thanks.  So now method ReleaseResourceToNativeWorld  how would it look like? will it be a MArshal.RealseComObject?

Comment: If we're working with a COM-objects manually (without any wrappers) I think yes, we can treat ReleaseComObject as a method that return native resource to their world.

Comment: thanks, so what is "native"? I have a Interop reference to it and I have created a .NET custom control and dropped that COM into it , so to be treated like a .NET control...so in this scenario am I working with it Native? or it is its .NET version? Thanks.